# Is $\mathbb{R}$ a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module

I found out that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module, because it can not be a direct summand of a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. What about $\mathbb{R}$, is $\mathbb{R}$ a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

I would say that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module with the same argument as for $\mathbb{Q}$, but I'm not sure, or is it wrong?

Comment: HINT: $\Bbb{Q}$ is a direct summand of $\Bbb{R}$. If $\Bbb{R}$ were projective, then $\Bbb{Q}$ would be projective as well.

Comment: @Crostul Why are you 1/ answering the question in the comments, 2/ contriving your answer in the form of a hint when the answer is completely immediate once you understand the hint?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Actually my comment may not seem so obvious to a beginner, so I call it a hint.

Comment: @Crostul You misunderstand. Coming up with your comment is not easy. But if you read the question, OP already knows that the rationals aren't projective, and that a direct summand of a projective is projective. Your answer is not a hint, it's a full answer with the word "Hint" in front and the last sentence missing.

Comment: @Najib it's still a hint, OP has to figure out why $\mathbb{Q}$ is a direct summand of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: thank you! yes, I am a beginner in abstract algebra and I know only a little bit for algebraic topolgy. I definitely have to elaborate Chrostul's hint for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't even embed in a free group, so it cannot be a summand thereof.

Indeed, let's prove that the only divisible subgroup of a free group is trivial. Let $F=\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ be free. Take a nonzero element $t=(n_x)_{x\in X}$ and consider the positive lowest common multiple $m$ of all the coefficients $n_x$. Then there is no element $u\in F$ such that $2mu=t$. Thus $t$ belongs to no divisible subgroup of $F$.

Comment: thanks, nice! But I still need time to understand and deliberate your answer completely

Comment: @toto An abelian (additive) group $G$ is divisible if, for every $x\in G$ and every integer $n>0$, there exists $y\in G$ with $ny=x$ (for short, $x$ is divisible by any positive integer). The idea is that a nonzero element of a free group is only divisible by at most a finite number of integers, so no nonzero element can belong to a divisible subgroup (where it would be divisible by *all* positive integers).

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\Bbb{Q}$ is a direct summand of $\Bbb{R}$: hence $\Bbb{R}$ is not projective.

To show that $\Bbb{Q}$ is a direct summand of $\Bbb{R}$, you need the Axiom of Choice: since $\Bbb{R}$ is a $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space, pick a basis $B$ such that $1 \in B$. Then
$$\Bbb{R} = \Bbb{Q} \oplus \Bbb{Q}(B \setminus \{ 1\})$$
as $\Bbb{Q}$-vector spaces. This implies that this direct sum is valid as $\Bbb{Z}$-modules as well.